# Python while loop is pausing

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to do multiple while loops but somehow they don't work. I already searched the internet but none of the problems I found has the same issue.

So here is the code containing only the necessary information. I am basically opening a socket, giving an in input (i\n) and receiving the output in the first step. I want to continue receiving the output until I have some specific characters xxx in the output. Then I want to go to the elif statement in the next loop.

```
def netcat(h, p):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((h,p))

    i = 0
    a = True
    while a == True:
        socket_list=[sys.stdin, s]
        r,w,x = select.select(socket_list, [], [])

        if i==0:
            time.sleep(1)
            message = s.recv(1024)
            print(message)
            s.send("i\n")
            sys.stdout.flush()

            while "xxx" not in message:
                message = s.recv(1024)
                print(message)
            i+=1
        elif i==1:
            print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                        i+=1

        print("hello")

    server.close()
```

What I would expect the code to do is to print the **message** from the if statement, then print **hello**, then the message from the elif statement and then **hello** over and over again because the while loop is still active. So in summary this is the expected output:

```
message
hello
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
hello
hello
hello
hello...
```

What it really prints is

```
message
hello
```

and then it finishes.

What I found out is that if I comment out the following lines:

```
                while "xxx" not in message:
                    message = s.recv(1024)
                    print(message)
```

it works as expected. The **hello** at the end of the code gets printed to the screen over and over again. I just don't get it why this second while loop has anything to do with it. I would really appreciate help here.

Since the working code was requested, here is also the full code. The hostname and port are from a CTF which is still working so you will be interacting with the CTF-server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import time
import select
import sys

base64="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/ ="
hostname = "18.188.70.152"
port = 36150

def netcat(h, p):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((h,p))

    i = 0
    a = True
    b = True
    while a == True:
        socket_list=[sys.stdin, s]
        r,w,x = select.select(socket_list, [], [])

        if i==0:
            time.sleep(1)           
            message = s.recv(1024)      
            print(message)          
            s.send("i\n")           
            sys.stdout.flush()

            while "flag" not in message:
                message = s.recv(1024)
                print(message)
            txtfile = message[9:38]
            print(txtfile)
            i+=1
        elif i==1:
            print("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
            i+=1
        print("hello")

    server.close()


netcat(hostname, port)
```

Comment: Another info: when running the code in the terminal it seems like the while loop is still open since the terminal only shows blank space at the end but it does not show the usual line username@machine:folders (on linux).

Comment: Please post the working code. Your code has a few problems...

Comment: Also, `server` the bottom of your code is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing event-based code (`select.select()`) with blocking synchronous code (your small `while` loop with the `s.recv()`).

If you want your code not to block, every `recv()` needs to be paired up with a preceding `select()`.

Not only that, but you must also check the returned values from `select()`. Only `s.recv()` if `s` was in the first returned list. If you `s.recv()` in any other case, the code will also block on the receive call.

Update:

Try something along the lines of:

```
not_done = True
while not_done:
    read_sockets, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin, s], [], [])

    if s in read_sockets:
        message = s.recv(1024)
        print(message)

        ... more code ...

        if 'flag' in message:
            ... react on flag ...

        if 'quit' in message:
            not_done = False

    ... processing of other sockets or file descriptors ...
```

The important point being that there is only this **one** `s.recv()` in the if branch that checks for whether select detected something was received.

The outer `while` will just come back to the same `if` branch later when additional data was received.

Note that processing `stdin` alongside socket code is tricky and will likely also block at some point. You will likely have to put the terminal into raw mode or something first and then be ready to process partial lines yourself as well as maybe also echoing the input back to the user.

Update:

If you want to do something while no message was received, you can give a timeout to `select()` and then do other processing if there was nothing received on the socket. Something like this:

```
say_hello_from_now_on = False

not_done = True
while not_done:
    read_sockets, _, _ = select.select([s], [], [], 1)

    if s in read_sockets:
        message = s.recv(1024)
        print(message)

        say_hello_from_now_on = True

    elif say_hello_from_now_on:
        print("hello")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. Could you please give me an example of how the select would need to be combined with the recv()?

Comment: @Loeli try something like the outline I updated the answer with.

Comment: I tried it now with your suggestion and I changed the while loop to only containing one recv but it still does not work. If I would not need the stdin how could I improve the code so it works? Sorry for all those questions but I am a bit new to this.

Comment: So you want it to constantly print hello when no message was received? You can achieve that by using a `select()` call with a timeout. If the `read_sockets` doesn't contain `s`, just print `hello`. Or do you want it to print hello only after the first message was received?

Comment: @Loeli I also added consuming the other 2 lists from the `select()` call which I missed before, sorry about that. With that error of mine the code would never have entered the `recv` branch of the `if`.

Comment: The "hello" was just there so I could check if the while loop is pausing or not. The thing I want to do is to print the receiving data to the screen, then send the server the message "i\n", again print receiving to screen, then send the server "n\n", print to screen and so on. What I did now was to insert `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` after the inner while loop and it worked. But I am not sure if this is a proper way to do this.

Comment: The proper way is not to use an inner while loop. You just rely on the code going back to the select call constantly and if it receives 1 item, process only that 1 item. And for more elaborate processing, you keep state alongside in variables that tell you how to react next.

Comment: I got it working now, thanks a lot! Just some more question to clarify the situation a bit: 
-the recv(1024) function will stop everything until it receives 1024bit?
-what does the select function do and what is going on with the timer?

Comment: No, `recv(1024)` will not wait for 1024 bytes. It will receive whatever is in the receive buffer, but only **up to** 1024 bytes. If data comes in at a high enough rate, `recv(1024)` will only return the first 1024 and leave the remaining data in the receive buffer for the **next** `recv()` call to return (i.e. it won't be lost, only split up).

Comment: The `select.select()` properly waits for something to happen on all file descriptors and sockets you give to it. This is particularly important if you have multiple of them at the same time, because you don't know in advance on which of them something will happen next. But this is also important if you want to do other periodic work alongside, which is what the timeout is for. Without the timeout, `select()` will wait until something happens, possibly indefinitely. With the timeout, it will set a limit on how long it will wait even if there was no activity on the sockets or file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check your indentation, try installing and running autopep8 on your code and see if that fixes any of your issues.

[edit] user has updated their question and it's clear that this isn't the answer.